# Analogy between words word2vec

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, word2vec

I am going through Stanford CS224n lectures and in the second lecture the following thing is mentioned :
[image]

But when I tried to do the same thing using vector differences I am getting a different result.

```
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('data/wiki-news-300d-1M.vec')
def analogy(x1, x2, y1):
    vector = np.add(model[y1], np.subtract(model[x2], model[x1]))
    return model.most_similar(positive=[vector], topn=1)

analogy("man", "king", "woman")
-> [('king', 0.8655095100402832)]
```

But if I use this method:

```
def analogy1(x1, x2, y1):
    result = model.most_similar(positive=[y1, x2], negative=[x1])
    return result[0]

analogy1("man", "king", "woman")
->('queen', 0.7515910863876343)
```

Could someone please help me what am I doing wrong or if I understood it wrong?

Link to video lecture: http://onlinehub.stanford.edu/cs224/190110-cs224n-1080

Comment: I am getting the same results, and not finding answers. :( Maybe try adding the "gensim" tag?